# Shell script to find the arrays size of cobol programs

Tags: shell, cobol

Can we write a shell script for finding the size of arrays in cobol programs dynamicaly like what is the maximum size of array and how much array is filled.

Comment: Show some sample input code please. Not everyone here speaks cobol.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Prashanth: Did the given answer "worked for you"? If yes: consider marking it as "accepted". If not: are there specific things missing?

Answer (score 5):

Question 1: Can we reliable find out via something (in this case a shell script) what the maximum array is used in some programming language (in this case COBOL)?

Answer: No - often you'd have a dynamic access (accessed by a variable) and is isn't reliable to know how much is used if you don't run the program with all the possible inputs.

Question 2: Can we write a shell script finding the size of arrays in some COBOL program?

Answer: Yes, if you don't use the 2002+ `OCCURS DYNAMIC` (where the `DEPENDING ON` will dynamically set the size) and don't use the IBM extension `OCCURS UNBOUNDED` (where the `DEPENDING ON` is used for defining the size and an external allocation is needed). This leaves `array OCCURS [min [TO]] max`.
Just `grep` (or `findstr` if you're locked on Windows) for `OCCURS` which will have the maximum size behind it. As it may be on a new line you'd need to remove the line breaks before checking (for example with `tr '\n\ ' '` , if the files may contain DOS line breaks an additional `tr '\r\ ' '`). As you may have an inline comment in you'd need to replace all comments before. Depending on the format (I'd assume fixed-form reference format) you'd have to remove the non-code parts of each line first and cater for continuation lines.
If you have the option it is likely much easier to pre-process the sources with a compiler (I've used the preprocessing the free GnuCOBOL compiler for a similar code investigation once) or even use the symbol table of the source listing, if it provides this (GnuCOBOL does have it). It comes down to a very simple `grep` in this case.